# Requiring SSH-key Login From Specific IP Ranges

Tags: remote-access, ssh

I need to be able to access my server (Ubuntu 8.04 LTS) from remote sites, but I'd like to worry a bit less about password complexity.  Thus, I'd like to require that SSH keys be used for login instead of name/password.  However, I still have a lot to learn about security, and having already badly broken a test box when I was trying to set this up, I'm acutely aware of the chance of screwing myself while trying to accomplish this.  So I have a second goal: I'd like to require that certain IP ranges (e.g. 10.0.0.0/8) may log in with name/password, but everyone else must use an SSH key to log in.

How can I satisfy both of these goals?

There already exists a [very similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/117965) here, but I can't quite figure out how to get to what I want from that information.

Current tactic: reading through the PAM documentation (pam_access looks promising) and looking at /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

**Edit:** Alternatively, is there a way to specify that certain users must authenticate with SSH keys, and others may authenticate with name/password?

---

**Solution that's currently working:**

> ```
> # Globally deny logon via password, only allow SSH-key login.  
> PasswordAuthentication no  
>
> # But allow connections from the LAN to use passwords.  
> Match Address 192.168.*.*  
>     PasswordAuthentication yes
> ```

The Match Address block can also usefully be a Match User block, answering my secondary question.  For now I'm just chalking the failure to parse CIDR addresses up to a quirk of my install, and resolving to try again when I go to Ubuntu 10.04 not too long from now.  PAM turns out not to be necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure how PAM would need to fit into this.  With a recent version of SSH (like what is available on 8.04) it should be as easy as using a Match blocks for the address space you wish to allow.

So your sshd_config should contain something like this.

```
# global option no password auth (keys only)
PasswordAuthentication no

# permit password from rfc1918
Match Address 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: I see that I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Drat.  The "Match" isn't parsing correctly, resulting in a global requirement to log on with keys.

Comment: Are you sure you got the syntax right for the net/mask?  I did test the above on my 9.10 system, and checked the sshd_config man page on a 8.04 system to make sure the Match was documented there.

Comment: I copied and pasted - I will consult the man page on the given system and try again.

Comment: Try with just a single network instead of a list maybe?

Comment: Oh for pity's sake.  I think it goes through the file line by line and matches the first applicable rule.  Logical enough.  But that means that when I copied and pasted your example verbatim (first sign of trouble) I wound up with a global Deny.  When I put the "Match Address" line _above_ the global line, things started working.

Comment: - no, it appears to have just set the opposite global preference.  Very puzzling.

Comment: Global configuration options must always be placed before any Match statements.  I should have mentioned that.  From the man -- *If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the file.*

Comment: I've tried several variations on these five lines, and all I can get out of them is a global keys-only or a global keys-and-passwords.

Comment: Also, just to be absolutely clear, this is how I'm doing it.  I am editing the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on the box in question.  After editing, sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart.  Test local-network login, test WAN login.  Am I missing something important?

Comment: Do not put any spaces between the comma, otherwise it breaks.